# Unable to parse links from the subsequent pages utilizing the requests module

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I've created a script to scrape links to different reports from a [webpage](https://efdsearch.senate.gov/search/home/). To generate the links, it is required to fill out [the form](https://ibb.co/kSQ2PKr) first. Then clicking on the `search reports` button should lead to the data-laden table.

The links are under the `report type` column in a table. However, the results are displayed across multiple pages. ***The script can grab the links from the first page, but I can't figure out why it fails to grab links from the next pages.***

```
import requests
from pprint import pprint
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base = 'https://efdsearch.senate.gov{}'
token_link = 'https://efdsearch.senate.gov/search/home/'
report_link = 'https://efdsearch.senate.gov/search/report/data/'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'Host': 'efdsearch.senate.gov',
    'Origin': 'https://efdsearch.senate.gov',
    'Referer': 'https://efdsearch.senate.gov/search/',
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
}

payload = {
    'prohibition_agreement': '1',
    'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ''
}


with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers.update(headers)
    res = s.get(token_link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    payload['csrfmiddlewaretoken'] = soup.select_one("input[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']")['value']
    headers['X-Csrftoken'] = soup.select_one("input[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']")['value']
    s.headers.update(headers)
    res = s.post(token_link,data=payload)

    page = 0
    draw = 0

    while True:
        params_ = 'draw=' + str(draw) + '&columns%5B0%5D%5Bdata%5D=0&columns%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B1%5D%5Bdata%5D=1&columns%5B1%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B2%5D%5Bdata%5D=2&columns%5B2%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B2%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B3%5D%5Bdata%5D=3&columns%5B3%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B3%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B4%5D%5Bdata%5D=4&columns%5B4%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B4%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&order%5B0%5D%5Bcolumn%5D=1&order%5B0%5D%5Bdir%5D=asc&order%5B1%5D%5Bcolumn%5D=0&order%5B1%5D%5Bdir%5D=asc&start=' + str(page) + '&length=25&search%5Bvalue%5D=&search%5Bregex%5D=false&report_types=%5B7%2C+11%2C+10%2C+14%5D&filer_types=%5B1%5D&submitted_start_date=01%2F01%2F2023+00%3A00%3A00&submitted_end_date=11%2F30%2F2023+23%3A59%3A59&candidate_state=&senator_state=&office_id=&first_name=&last_name='
        resp = s.post(report_link,data=params_)
        try:
            resp.json()['data']
        except Exception:
            break
        for item in resp.json()['data']:
            last_name = item[0]
            first_name = item[1]
            full_name = item[2]
            report_link_relative = BeautifulSoup(item[3],"lxml").select_one("a[href]")['href']
            report_link = base.format(report_link_relative)
            date = item[4]
            print(report_link)

        draw = resp.json()['draw']
        page+=25
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

api_url = "https://efdsearch.senate.gov/search/report/data/"

data = {
    "draw": 1,
    "columns[0][data]": "0",
    "columns[0][name]": "",
    "columns[0][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[0][orderable]": "true",
    "columns[0][search][value]": "",
    "columns[0][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[1][data]": "1",
    "columns[1][name]": "",
    "columns[1][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[1][orderable]": "true",
    "columns[1][search][value]": "",
    "columns[1][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[2][data]": "2",
    "columns[2][name]": "",
    "columns[2][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[2][orderable]": "true",
    "columns[2][search][value]": "",
    "columns[2][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[3][data]": "3",
    "columns[3][name]": "",
    "columns[3][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[3][orderable]": "true",
    "columns[3][search][value]": "",
    "columns[3][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[4][data]": "4",
    "columns[4][name]": "",
    "columns[4][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[4][orderable]": "true",
    "columns[4][search][value]": "",
    "columns[4][search][regex]": "false",
    "order[0][column]": "1",
    "order[0][dir]": "asc",
    "order[1][column]": "0",
    "order[1][dir]": "asc",
    "start": 0,
    "length": "25",
    "search[value]": "",
    "search[regex]": "false",
    "report_types": "[7, 11, 10, 14, 15]",
    "filer_types": "[1]",
    "submitted_start_date": "01/01/2012 00:00:00",
    "submitted_end_date": "12/31/2023 23:59:59",
    "candidate_state": "",
    "senator_state": "",
    "office_id": "",
    "first_name": "",
    "last_name": "",
}

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/118.0",
    "Referer": "https://efdsearch.senate.gov/search/home/",
    "Origin": "https://efdsearch.senate.gov",
}

with requests.session() as s:
    s.headers.update(headers)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(
        s.get("https://efdsearch.senate.gov/search/home/").content, "html.parser"
    )
    token = soup.select_one('[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]')["value"]

    soup = BeautifulSoup(
        s.post(
            "https://efdsearch.senate.gov/search/home/",
            data={"prohibition_agreement": "1", "csrfmiddlewaretoken": token},
        ).content,
        "html.parser",
    )

    token = soup.select_one('[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]')["value"]
    s.headers.update({"X-CSRFToken": s.cookies["csrftoken"]})

    all_data = []
    while True:
        d = s.post(api_url, data=data).json()

        if not d["data"]:
            break

        all_data.extend(d["data"])
        data["draw"] += 1
        data["start"] += 25

        print(len(all_data))

    df = pd.DataFrame(
        all_data,
        columns=["First Name", "Last Name", "Office", "Report Type", "Date"],
    )
    print(df.tail())
```

Prints:

```
     First Name Last Name                 Office                                                                                                                                            Report Type        Date
3462       Todd     Young  Young, Todd (Senator)                                      <a href="/search/view/annual/4b216e94-99a7-43f5-91ae-a6c8a2d75cc8/" target="_blank">Annual Report for CY 2021</a>  05/16/2022
3463       Todd     Young  Young, Todd (Senator)                                      <a href="/search/view/annual/39abb643-28ab-4f68-a16e-80881a661876/" target="_blank">Annual Report for CY 2022</a>  05/11/2023
3464       Todd     Young                Senator  <a href="/search/view/extension-notice/regular/5c3fe079-85b1-49eb-bbda-59b5210bc9c6/" target="_blank">Annual Report for 2019 Due Date Extension 1</a>  04/16/2020
3465       Todd     Young  Young, Todd (Senator)                                      <a href="/search/view/annual/cff56103-021e-498f-b2c4-b0fae3095606/" target="_blank">Annual Report for CY 2017</a>  05/15/2018
3466       Todd     Young  Young, Todd (Senator)                                      <a href="/search/view/annual/e22c5c63-4949-48cd-967a-e53137b26aa0/" target="_blank">Annual Report for CY 2019</a>  08/13/2020
```